# SchurDecomposition returns matrices which are not a Schur decomposition

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

A Schur decomposition is a decomposition $M = Q T Q^\dagger$ where $Q$ is unitary, and $T$ upper triangular.

It is implemented in Mathematica by `{Q, T} = SchurDecomposition[M]`. However, I find (Version 12.0.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit)) that this function fails without warning in certain cases. For example:

```
    A = {{1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1}};
    B = {{1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}};
    M = A + 0.8 B;
    {Q, T} = SchurDecomposition[M];
    T
```

> ```
> {{0.6, 5.97374*10^-16, 1.66082*10^-16, -1.},
>  {0., 1.8, -0.2, -2.47246*10^-16},
>  {0., 0.8, 1.8, 2.51215*10^-16},
>  {0.,0.,0.,3.}}
> ```

which is not triangular

```
    UpperTriangularMatrixQ[T]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

As $T$ is defined to be triangular, this result seems to represent an error.

I note that in this case a small numerical perturbation seems to make to make the function work again

```
    M2 = M + 10^-10 I IdentityMatrix[4];
    {Q, T} = SchurDecomposition[M2];
    UpperTriangularMatrixQ[T]
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

Is this a bug? Is it reproduced by others?

Comment: The matrix $\mathbf T$ returned by `SchurDecomposition[]` is *block* upper triangular if the matrix has complex eigenvalues; i.e., you are actually computing the [Murnaghan-Wintner form](https://doi.org/10.1073/pnas.17.7.417). You should add the `RealBlockDiagonalForm -> False` setting (as noted in the docs) if you want an upper triangular result.

Comment: I see... how very confusing. Thank you!